# api/graphql is not found while using nestjs angular universal setup

Tags: angular, graphql, nestjs, angular-universal

I cant find the GraphQL endpoint in nestjs angular universal setup. I add ssr/angularuniversal using ng add @nestjs/ng-universal. ssr is working other endpoints r working as well but I cant find GraphQL end point

```
// app.module.ts(nestjs)
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AngularUniversalModule } from '@nestjs/ng-universal';
import { join } from 'path';

import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';

import { HelloModule } from './src/hello/hello.module';
@Module({
  imports: [
    HelloModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: './server/schema.gql',
    }),

    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
      viewsPath: join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser'),
      bundle: require('../server/main'),
      liveReload: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
// hello.module.ts(nestjs)
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HelloResolver } from './hello.resolver';
import { HelloController } from './hello.controller';
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [HelloController],
  providers: [HelloResolver],
})
export class HelloModule {}
// hello.resolver.ts
import { Resolver, Query } from 'type-graphql';

@Resolver()
export class HelloResolver {
  @Query(() => String)
  hello() {
    return 'hello';
  }
}
```

```
# schema.gql
# -----------------------------------------------
# !!! THIS FILE WAS GENERATED BY TYPE-GRAPHQL !!!
# !!!   DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BY YOURSELF   !!!
# -----------------------------------------------

type Query {
  hello: String!
}
```

I think api/graphql should serve graphql PlayGround but it redirects to "/"

Answer (score 0):

The `GraphQLModule` actually does not take into account any globalPrefix you have set, so it's endpoint is just at `/graphql` unless you specify otherwise